# Gamma matrices in the 4-momentum operator

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices

I'm trying to compute the operator $\hat P^\mu$ from
$$\hat P^i=\int d^3x\hat\tau^{0i}$$ where $\hat\tau^{\mu\nu}$ is the stress energy tensor for the Dirac Lagrangian. In my case I have
$$\hat\tau^{0i}=\frac{1}{2}\left(i\bar{\psi}\gamma^0\partial^i\psi+i\bar\psi\gamma^i\partial^0\psi\right)$$
I'm stuck when I have to calculate the term $i\bar\psi\gamma^i\partial^0\psi$. I know that $\bar u_i(k)\gamma^\mu u_j(k)=2k^\mu\delta_{ij}$ but I don't know how to treat
$$\bar u_i(k)\gamma^\mu v_j(k)$$
or $$\bar v_i(k)\gamma^\mu u_j(k)$$